# LaTeX gives warning - empty label `' multiply defined

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings

I have a LaTeX document that works fine, but it does give a warning message every time I compile it. Here is the text of the warning message:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `' multiply defined.
```

The name of the label that is multiply defined appears to be an empty string. I am confused about this, but I have had trouble searching for it online because the key element is the empty string, which does not make for a good search term. Does anyone know what this warning message could mean?

I can post details of the document in question as needed, but at this point I have no idea what parts could be important.

Got it. I guess I didn't realize that bibliography items counted as labels - since I never had any intention of referring to them anywhere, I left all of their labels blank initially.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: A [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) is how to determine what parts are important.  It might take some work if the original document is long/complicated, but constructing it can sometimes even make the problem obvious to non-experts.

Comment: A label is something that you create in a document.  So a web search for the *culprit* label will not be useful to you.    From your description, short of a MWE, you might want to search your document for occurrences of the `\label` command.  In particular, you might have a few `\label{}` scattered throughout your document.

Answer (score 6):

A label is something that you create in a document.  So, you'll want to look through your document for something like `\label` and see how the label has been defined.

The syntax is

```
 \label{<label-name>}
```

where `<label-name>` is something that you create.

If you have multiple *empty* labels created, such as

```
\label{}
```

or something equivalent, then you'll get the error you've reported.

One way to *bug-chase* this and a generally good practice is to give *useful* and meaningful names to your labels.  For example, if you have an equation, then you can write

```
\label{eqn:<short description of equation>}
```

If, for example, the label is for a section introducing the definition of a martingale, then you can write

```
\label{sec:defn_of_martingale}
```

By doing this, your labels will be meaningful and easier to understand in your source document.  But also, it'll much easier to find *duplicate* labels.

Answer (score 5):

To complete A.Ellett's excellent answer with another possible culprit which I encountered in a report that I'm reviewing. Multiple

```
\bibitem{}
```

produce the same warning.

Comment: Thanks, but note that you may need to compile twice before the warning goes away.

Comment: This really deserves more upvotes as I don't think most users who get this error are sticking in empty labels (why would they).  It is however perfectly reasonable to drop in incomplete bibliography items to return to later then get a confusing warning.